# Enabling checkbox with different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, checkbox, textbox

Ok, I've been coding a website for a while now and this the first "insurmountable" problem I haven't found an aswer for, so now I'm turning to you, the experts.

On my form I have three drop-down menus, one textbox and one disabled checkbox. I want it to work so that when a user has selected an option from each drop-down menu and written something on the textbox, the checkbox becomes enabled.

I have found [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/JKmkL/1/) when I have been looking for a solution and it's very similar to my problem. However, when I try to add another drop-down menu, it still enables the button when I select an option from the first menu and completely ignores the second menu. I'm sorry, I'm new to Jquery/JavaScript and I just think it should work that way when the class names are same on both menus (jQuery class selector: ('.dropdown')).

I have also found [a similar code with textboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/WQcdq/4/). I just don't know how to combine these codes so it would act the way I want.

Comment: Wow! I leave my question, go to sleep and first thing in the morning I check the answers and find even three with five working solutions! This is definitely the place I'll ask for help in the future when I come across these "insurmountable" problems. Thank You all so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JKmkL/109/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.required').change(function() {
        var done=true;
        $('.required').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $('.myCheckBox').prop('disabled',true);
                done=false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(done){$('.myCheckBox').prop('disabled',false);}
    });
});
```

And add class `required` to the elements.

**Edit:**

The code above assumes that the default `<option>` has `value=""`. If not, you can use http://jsfiddle.net/JKmkL/114/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.required').change(function() {
        var done=true;
        function quit(){
            $('.myCheckBox').prop('disabled',true);
            done=false;
            return false;
        }
        $('.required.dropdown').each(function(){
            if($(this).children(':selected').hasClass("disablenext")){
                return quit();
            }
        });
        $('.required[type=text]').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                return quit();
            }
        });
        if(done){$('.myCheckBox').prop('disabled',false);}
    });
});
```

**Edit 2:**

If you want to show a div when the checkbox is checked and hide it when the checkbox is disabled, use

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.required').change(function() {
        var done=true;
        function quit(){
            $('.myCheckBox').prop('disabled',true).removeAttr('checked');
            done=false;
            $('#div2').addClass('hide');
            return false;
        }
        $('.required.dropdown').each(function(){
            if($(this).children(':selected').hasClass("disablenext")){
                return quit();
            }
        });
        $('.required[type=text]').each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                return quit();
            }
        });
        if(done){$('.myCheckBox').prop('disabled',false);}
    });
    $('.myCheckBox').click(function(){
        $('#div2')[(this.checked?'remove':'add')+'Class']('hide');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide{display:none}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JKmkL/133/

Comment: You really shouldn't assume that the value of the first option item in the list is always going to be blank. Some people choose to provide a value to that item. I'll upvote if you change the code to reflect the dynamics of forms. Otherwise, for future users, this could be caustic.

Comment: @Oriol I chose your example and modified it a little so it also removes checkbox checking if user chooses first option from any drop-down menus or erases text from textbox. The problem is the hidden div, that appears when checkbox is checked and of course disappears when user unchecks the checkbox. It just doesn't disappear when checkbox becomes unchecked by jQuery. How do I solve this problem? Div is shown and hidden by JavaScript, can this cause the problem? Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/JKmkL/132/

Comment: @Oriol Very, very nice! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**I assume that dropdown's default value is value=""**

```
   $('#form_submit_button').click(function(){  

        $('.checkbox').attr('disabled',true);
        var all_selected = true;

        $('.dropdown').each(function(){

             if(!$(this).val())
             {
                  all_selected = false; 
             }
        });


        if(!$('#text_box').text())
        {
           all_selected = false;
        }

        if(all_selected)
        {      
            $('.checkbox').attr('disabled',false);
        }       
  });
```

Comment: You're making an assumption that the first item in the select list will always be `<option value="" selected=""> Default </option>` If that's not the case, this code will not work.

Comment: yes , i assume that , also in his jsfiddle dropdown's default value is ""

Comment: It's important to understand that future users will find this question eventually. You should make a note about the circumstances under which this will work. If you don't, and they're using a value, this code won't work and will likely only deter them. I'll upvote if you make either one of my suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, say the id for the three dropdowns are called `d1`, `d2`, and `d3`; textbox is `txt`; and checkbox is `chk`. You can then define a function that determines when the checkbox must be enabled:

```
function shouldEnableCheckbox() {
    var nonEmptyFields = $("#d1,#d2,#d3,#txt").filter(function() {
        return this.value;    
    });
    return nonEmptyFields.length == 4;
}
```

Essentially, you select all 4 elements, filter those that are non-empty, and compare the resulting filtered array with 4. If it is true, it means you should enable the checkbox.

Then, assign the [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to all 4 elements, invoke the previous function, and assign the result to the `disabled` property of the checkbox:

```
$("#d1,#d2,#d3,#txt").change(function() {
    $("#chk").prop("disabled", !shouldEnableCheckbox());
});​
```

Here's the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7RxU/)**, and another working, more generic **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wGmnY/)**, which uses a class instead of ids to identify the required elements.